# can we say "please squat up / down" to a person sitting / standing on the floor, respectively?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> **[squat](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/squat_1?q=squat)** ​[intransitive] squat (down) to sit on your heels with your knees bent up close to your body
>
> Children were squatting on the floor.
>
> When we saw them we squatted down behind a wall.

---

Sometimes, you need to wash your toddler's bottom. It is easier to do that when your child is in a squatting position.

When a person is sitting on the floor, could we say "**please squat up!**"

and when he is standing on the floor, could we say "**please squat down!**"

See the picture portrayed below

**Note:** people say "**sit down**" to a person who is standing & and say "**sit up**" to a person who is lying. If we can not say "**squat up**", then what does the adverb "**down**" in "**squat down**" mean?

[image]

Comment: Just say 'squat' in either case. Nobody says 'squat up'; squatting is always 'down'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, so, the adverb "down" is not similar to the "down" in "sit down" because we can say "sit up" but not "squat up". What does the adverb "down" mean?

Comment: 'Down' has its ordinary dictionary meaning of 'moving towards a lower place or position'.

Comment: I've never heard anyone say 'squat up', I suppose because we think of squatting as a position you go into from standing rather than from sitting or lying down. I suppose a parent might ask a child to 'lift their bottom off the floor' (or whatever they are sitting on).